# how to make custom audio player in blazor c# with full ability like regula audio player?

Tags: audio, blazor, audio-player

like the title i want to make custom audio player

i try use looping in C# send audioid,persentage of input,duration of audio to call js to calculate current time and then return value of current time to update C# component that have delay 1 sec problem is audio doesn't play smooth
this is js code:

```
function settProgress(audioId, percentage, duration) {
    var audio = document.getElementById(audioId);
        audio.currentTime = (duration * percentage) / 100;
    return audio.currentTime;
}
```

this is C# code when push play and pause button:

```
    private async Task PlayPause()
    {
        var audioElement = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("eval", "document.querySelector('#audio')");

        if (isPlaying)
        {

            ppaudio = @Icons.Material.Rounded.PlayArrow;
            await audioElement.InvokeVoidAsync("pause");
            isPlaying = false;
        }
        else
        {

            ppaudio = @Icons.Material.Rounded.Pause;
            await audioElement.InvokeVoidAsync("play");
            isPlaying = true;
            while (isPlaying)
            {
                var duration = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<double>("getAudiodur", audioUrl);
                var audioId = "audio";
                sliderValue = sliderValue + plus;
                var currset = await JS.InvokeAsync<double>("settProgress", audioId, sliderValue, duration);
                audiocurr = currset;
                currentTime =  FormatDuration(audiocurr);
                sliderValue =  Convert.ToDouble((100 / audioDuration) * audiocurr);
                if (sliderValue == 100)
                {
                    sliderValue = 0;
                    await audioElement.InvokeVoidAsync("play");
                    isPlaying = true;
                    StateHasChanged();
                }
                StateHasChanged();
                await Task.Delay(1000);


            }
        }


    }
```